# Python: Pandas cause invalid type of comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have two types of error data that need to corrected. One is with null and one is with Nan.

```
 >>> df_new
          Volume Price   
Date
2017-01-01 500  760
2017-01-02 null 760
2017-01-03 50   770
2017-01-04 null 780
```

Another type is with NaN

```
 >>> df_new
          Volume Price   
Date
2017-01-01 500  760
2017-01-02 NaN 760
2017-01-03 50  770
2017-01-04 NaN 780
```

How to replace both null and NaN data with 0?
My code working if either null or NaN but I can't work for both

```
volume = df_new['Volume'] == 'null' or df_new['Volume'].isnull()
df_new.loc[volume,'Volume'] = 0
df_new.replace('null',np.NaN,inplace=True)
df_new.iloc[0].fillna(df_new.iloc[1].Open,inplace=True)
```

it return error

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "", line 1, in
>     File
>   "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line
>   763, in wrapper    res = na_op(values, other)  File
>   "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line
>   718, in na_op    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")TypeError:
>   invalid type comparison

The code will work if `volume = df_new['Volume'] == 'null'` but this will not correct the data is it is NaN, and repalce with 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for replace `null` and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for replace `NaN`s and `None`s:

```
df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].replace('null', np.nan).fillna(0)
```

Or:

```
df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].replace('null', 0).fillna(0)
```

For detect `null` or `NaN`s add `|` for bitwise `or` and parentheses:

```
volume = (df_new['Volume'] == 'null') | (df_new['Volume'].isnull())
```

Comment: Sorry, It need to detect the pandas dataframe contains NaN or null first, is that correct? The probllem is in the `volume = df_new['Volume'] == 'null' or df_new['Volume'].isnull()`

Comment: Then need `volume = (df_new['Volume'] == 'null') | (df_new['Volume'].isnull())`

Comment: `volume = (df_new['Volume'] == 'null') | (df_new['Volume'].isnull())` still return error `TypeError: invalid type comparison`

Comment: Then try `volume = (df_new['Volume'].values == 'null') | (df_new['Volume'].isnull())`

Comment: Or `volume = (df_new['Volume'].astype(str) == 'null') | (df_new['Volume'].isnull())`,  because it seems there are mixed values - numeric with strings